# mod_redirect every request except a.php, b.php and c.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, tinyurl

I have searched Google and looked here but I haven't quite found the answer I am looking for.

I am working on a little project and part of it will allow shorturl redirects, similar to bit.ly or tinyurl.com.

I would like to allow visitors to be able to view pages a.php, b.php and c.php but everything else such as; domain.com/blahblahblah or domain.com/FirstName will be redirected to c.php which will look at the URL, then look in the DB to see if there is a matching value.  If there is then redirect them.

I have everything done except the catch all mod_redirect / .htaccess redirect.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(a\.php|b\.php|c\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ c.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I created a .htaccess file and added the following:

`code`
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(addme\.php|config\.php|index\.php|)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect.php?q=$1 [L]
`code`

When I typed domain.com/blahblahblah I got a 404 page not found.

I went to cpanel added a redirect from A to B. It created this code:

`code`
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^123$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com\/test\/" [R=301,L]
`code`

It worked. I wanted to try to make sure that my server was able to do redirected and that something was disabled.

Any idea?

Comment: The redirect.php is not on your whitelist.

Comment: I replaced the c.php with redirect.php from the code you gave me.  Was there something else I should have done?  My pages are index.php, addme.php, config.php and redirect.php. I just followed your format and replaced the a, b, c... with my page names.  Sorry to be such a bother.

Comment: Oh god, totally my bad. I'm having some troubles sifting out what you mean in your last comment. Try adding the redirect.php to your whitelist and tell me what happens

Comment: This is the code I used:
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(addme\.php|config\.php|index\.php|)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ redirect.php?q=$1 [L]`

Comment: `$1 !^(addme\.php|config\.php|index\.php|)` becomes `$1 !^(addme\.php|config\.php|index\.php|redirect\.php)`

Comment: Ok, everything works perfectly except one thing.  If I go to the root domain.com I get redirected.  If I type domain.com/index.php its OK. How can I add the root /?  Thanks again.

Comment: Looks like I got it.  'RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ redirect.php?q=$1 [L]'  Thanks a ton for your help!